# How to layout my android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a math application for my daughter. It shall consist of upper row with assignment to solve, some progress bar and then keypad on left and function pad on right. This is my idea:

[image]

I started with a linear layout holding set of linear layouts. Android studio argues that nested weights have bad performance. And I failed to have 4 rows of keypad besides 5 rows of functions. This is my current progress:

[image]

Then I used a table layout but it does not have row span. So I switched to a relative layout, but I failed to distribute rows evenly. The last attempt was grid layout, but again I cannot distribute the rows evenly.

Any idea, how to achieve my goal?

```js
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".CalcActivity"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/firstOperand"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/operator"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/secondOperand"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/equalView"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/resultView"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:onClick=""
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/progressImage"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cat"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="4"
        android:layout_column="4">
        <Button
            android:text="←"
            android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="*"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="/"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/digit7"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/digit8"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/digit9"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/digit4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/digit5"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3" />

    <Button
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/digit6"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="3" />

    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/digit1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/digit2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <Button
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/digit3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <Button
        android:text=","
        android:id="@+id/buttonComma"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/digit0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="5" />

    <Button
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/buttonResult"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="5" />

</GridLayout>
```

```css
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".CalcActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/firstOperand"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstOperand"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/operator"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/operator"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/secondOperand"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/secondOperand"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/equalView"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/equalView"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/resultView"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstOperand"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:onClick=""
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstOperand"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/seekBar"
        android:id="@+id/progressImage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cat"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressImage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="←"
        android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/digit7"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/digit7"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/digit8"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/digit8"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/digit9"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/buttonBackspace"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit7"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/digit4"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/digit4"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/digit5"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/digit5"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/digit6"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit4"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/digit1"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/digit1"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/digit2"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/digit2"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/digit3"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMinus"
        android:text="*"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text=","
        android:id="@+id/buttonComma"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonComma"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/digit0"
        style="@style/KeypadButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/digit1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/digit0"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/buttonResult"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".CalcActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/assignment">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="50"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="51"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="="
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="101"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cat"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="20px"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="←"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/upperDigits">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/middleDigits">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/lowDigits">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*"
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bottomDigits">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=","
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            style="@style/KeypadButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="="
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: both my and chiru's attempts with a relative layout ends with expanded progress bar section taking all available space.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like i almost did what you want using LinearLayout. Take a look of screenshot bro.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CalcActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="9" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="8" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="7" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="6" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="4" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="," />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:text="=" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="←" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="*" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/assignment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="50"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
            android:text="51"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
            android:text="="
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
            android:text="101"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/assignment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/assignment"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/progressImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As i don't have those styles, i have been forced to remove it.

[image: screenshot]

edited screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Nice combination @chiru. I just want to make it fill the screen. How to do it? Play with weights?

Comment: Test with different weights, margins and padding bro or even relativelayout setparentbottom = true might help u up.

Comment: I have been several times so close myself but I failed to stretch the layout to fill entire screen. Once I make it work I will accept your answer.

Comment: What about android studio hint "nested weights are bad for performance", shall I ignore it?

Comment: i'm using eclipse still, not sure about it. u can just google it bro. but take a look at my edited answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69987/discussion-between-leos-literak-and-chiru).

Comment: I hate this SO limitation. Nevermind, I will continue with the linear layout version without relative layout. I was very close, I expanded it over the screen, I just wanted to make function buttons column wider.